# Can we have a 16×16 favicon that does not look like “Lo.”?

Tags: bug, design

Our 16×16 favicon looks like this: [image: Favicon]. Here is a zoom:

[image: Large favicon]

My eyes read this as *Lo.,* and not as *La,* as it was probably intended. Can we please have the pixels tweaked to achieve something that looks more like an *a* or alternatively an *A?* For example something like this:

[image: Alternative]

Comment: Fill that blank pixel between the o and the tail in, and it'd be fine.